# MySQL : fetch cursor in while loop

Tags: mysql

I want to know what is that `while` loop is doing. Say I have the following table.

```
Person | num
------------
 A     | 10
 B     |  7
 C     |  3
```

And then I do the following, what is that nested `while` loop is doing?

```
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
            SELECT num FROM num_file;


DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000'
        SET done = 1;

    OPEN cur;
    FETCH cur INTO first_val;
    WHILE NOT done DO
        FETCH cur INTO second_val;
        IF NOT done THEN
            SET temp = second_val - first_val;
            SET first_val = second_val;
        END IF;
    END WHILE;
    CLOSE cur;
```

### --------

**Update:**
Is it taking the difference between each number? 
Eg. 10-7; 7-3;

Comment: you have an extra `END IF`. You aren't doing anything meaningful with `temp`. Sounds like you are confused.

Comment: You are asking what it is doing and I am saying (from my angle) that you have a faulty extra end if so what is the point in talking about code that won't run

Comment: sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: Ok so you just deleted a comment up there so it looks like I am talking to myself up there. Are you asking what your code is doing or How to Do a particular thing

Comment: Thx for the reply. I just want to know what the code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you had declared a variable `done` with default value 0.

A cursor for looping over values in `num` column in `num_file` table.

A handler which will set done=1, when all rows in cursor is fetched (Mysql returns error code 02000 if an attempt is made to fetch a row from that cursor again).

Then the cursor is opened. Now it contains rows with values of `num` column.

The while loop will be executed till done is set to 1.That is, till all rows are fetched.

Inside while loop, the difference between subsequent values of `num` column is calculated and stored in variable `temp` .